# Does the return code of a Process.Start call effect the caller's return code?

Tags: c#, .net, process

I have my console app *(TestEngine)* and it's launching an executable *(ikvm.exe)* using `ProcessStartInfo` and `Process.Start`. In an *msbuild script*, I call `TestEngine` many times with different parameters.

```
<Target Name="testDatasource">
    <Exec Command="TestEngine testDatasource" />
</Target>
<Target Name="testDocument">
    <Exec Command="TestEngine testDocument" />
</Target>
```

I'm using a single target to call all of these other targets.

```
<Target Name="testAll">
    <CallTarget Targets="testDatasource;testDocument;..." />
</Target>
```

The problem is that on the fourth call, the process that `TestEngine` launches is returning exit code 1, but for some reason, that's stopping the *testAll* target. `TestEngine` isn't setting the exit code, so I guess it's the launched process that's doing it - is that true? I'm searching through the docs, but I haven't found anything about this yet.

Comment: Sounds like `TestEngine` is observing that the process ended abnormally, and gave up. (normal exit would have returned an exit code of 0).